# How should I specify Rails model relationship in this case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, database-design

Supposed that I have 3 models in Rails: Post, Comment, and User. Each of them should have a one-to-one relationship with the Image model.

Should I go with:

```
class Post
  has_one :image
end

class Comment
  has_one :image
end

class User
  has_one :image
end

class Image
  # Foreign key references
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :comment
  belongs_to :user
end
```

or

```
class Post
  belongs_to :image # Foreign key reference
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :image # Foreign key reference
end

class User
  belongs_to :image # Foreign key reference
end

class Image
end
```

What is the advantages and disadvantages of each?
Is there any other well-known practice to handle this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the given data, there's no real difference between the two.

However...
At a later date... if you suddenly decide that you need two images for a post, you will need to have the post_id on the image, rather than an image_id on the post (or else you'll one stuck with only ever being able to have one image for post).

this means you're better off with belongs_to on the image-side, rather than the other-thing side.

Comment: I'm a bit uncomfortable having the Image table to store references to the other things. I think an Image should be agnostic to the model in which it is used. But, pragmatically I think your recommendation would be the best. Thanks!

Comment: a join-table would work too - but be a bit more complicated. It would then let you allow one image to be referenced by multiple other things (eg be on a page, but also be a profile picture)